Bubblegum createTree timeout
Issue
I encountered a timeout issue while using the createTree interface to create a Merkle tree. The method hangs until it times out.
     Error: Timeout of 1000000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
  at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
  at processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)

Code
Here is my code:
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  const user = anchor.Wallet.local().payer;
  it("init game!", async () => {   
    const game = new Game(provider);
    const umi = createUmi('http://localhost:8899')
        .use(mplBubblegum())
        .use(walletAdapterIdentity(user));
    const [tx, GameInfoPda] = await Game.initGame(user, umi);
}

client
   async initGame (user: Keypair, umi: Umi): Promise<[string, PublicKey]> {
          // create merkle tree
        const merkleTree = generateSigner(umi);
        console.log(`Creating Merkle Tree...${merkleTree.publicKey.toString()}`);
        const builder = await createTree(umi, {        
            merkleTree,
            maxDepth: 16,
            maxBufferSize: 64,
            canopyDepth: 15,
            public: true,
        });
       await builder.sendAndConfirm(umi,
            {
                send: {skipPreflight: true}
            }
        );     // <----- stuck here
       ...
}

Attempts made so far

change cluster to devnet
reduce the merkeltree maxdepth
The above methods didn’t work
modify code to await builder.sendAndConfirm(umi);, Saw what might be causing the problem：

     ProgramErrorNotRecognizedError: The program [mplBubblegum] at address [BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY] raised an error that is not recognized by the programs registered on the SDK. Please check the underlying program error below for more details.

Source: Program > mplBubblegum [BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY]

Caused By: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xbc1

Program Logs:
| Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
| Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
| Program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY invoke [1]
| Program log: Instruction: CreateTree
| Program log: AnchorError caused by account: log_wrapper. Error Code: InvalidProgramExecutable. Error Number: 3009. Error Message: Program account is not executable.
| Program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY consumed 5277 of 399850 compute units
| Program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY failed: custom program error: 0xbc1

      at Object.resolveError (node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi-program-repository/src/createDefaultProgramRepository.ts:136:29)
      at Object.sendTransaction (node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi-rpc-web3js/src/createWeb3JsRpc.ts:335:42)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi/src/TransactionBuilder.ts:359:23)

Does anyone know why this is happening? Or is there an issue with my code above? Thanks.

    ProgramErrorNotRecognizedError: The program [mplBubblegum] at address [BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY] raised an error that is not recognized by the programs registered on the SDK. Please check the underlying program error below for more details.

Source: Program > mplBubblegum [BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY]

Caused By: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xbc1

Program Logs:
| Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
| Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
| Program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY invoke [1]
| Program log: Instruction: CreateTree
| Program log: AnchorError caused by account: log_wrapper. Error Code: InvalidProgramExecutable. Error Number: 3009. Error Message: Program account is not executable.
| Program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY consumed 5277 of 399850 compute units
| Program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY failed: custom program error: 0xbc1

      at Object.resolveError (node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi-program-repository/src/createDefaultProgramRepository.ts:136:29)
      at Object.sendTransaction (node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi-rpc-web3js/src/createWeb3JsRpc.ts:335:42)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi/src/TransactionBuilder.ts:359:23)

The cause of the above error is that the logWrapper program is not present on the local cluster.
Solution
solana-test-validator -r --bpf-program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY ./bubblegum.so --bpf-program cmtDvXumGCrqC1Age74AVPhSRVXJMd8PJS91L8KbNCK ./compressionProgram.so --bpf-program noopb9bkMVfRPU8AsbpTUg8AQkHtKwMYZiFUjNRtMmV logWrapper.so


The error suggests you are passing in the wrong program address for it, which is weird.
Below is the umi TS script
import {
    generateSigner,
    keypairIdentity,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi"; // ^0.8.10
import { createTree, mplBubblegum } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum"; // ^4.1.0
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults"; // ^0.8.10

export const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from([]));

umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair)).use(mplBubblegum());

async function createBubblegumTree() {
    const merkleTree = generateSigner(umi);
    const builder = await createTree(umi, {
        merkleTree,
        maxDepth: 14,
        maxBufferSize: 64,
    });
    (await builder).sendAndConfirm(umi, { send: { skipPreflight: true } });
}

createBubblegumTree().then().catch(console.error);


Thanks for your reply. I have already tried that, and it didn’t work.
       await builder.sendAndConfirm(umi, {
            send: {
              skipPreflight: true,
        }});


are you doing any assertions in your tests?

Does it work if you run the create Merkle tree IX on its own?

Currently, I am not making any assertions in the test. How can I run the create Merkle tree IX separately?

I enabled simulation and saw the cause of the issue.

Using your newly updated code also encounters the aforementioned issue. The main problem now is 'AnchorError caused by account: log_wrapper. Error Code: InvalidProgramExecutable.' However, I followed the bubblegum official documentation to write the code, but I didn't see where to pass the log_wrapper account. Do you know that?

That's strange, these helpers should fill in the required accounts to pass into the instruction.  Also, what version of the packages are you using? Let me ping the MPL discord.

I'm using the latest version 4.1.0 of the @metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum package. Actually, the suggestion to 'pass the log_wrapper account correctly' was the help I got in the mpl Discord, but no one answered how to pass this account.
